# content_tag :i not displaying rails fontawesome

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do this

```
<i class="fas fa-retweet fa-lg></i><span>Retweet</span>
```

This is my code

```
 content_tag :div, class: "flex" do
    content_tag :i, "", class: "fas fa-retweet fa-lg"
    content_tag :span, " Retweet"
 end
```

I really don't understand why `content_tag :i, "", class: "fas fa-retweet fa-lg"` is not showing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby on Rails 4 does not display content\_tag :i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245922/ruby-on-rails-4-does-not-display-content-tag-i)

Comment: hi again sampat! no does not :(( thank you for checking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
content_tag :i, ('<i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>').html_safe
```

It should work.

You can also pass it in a block (more elegant way):

```
<%= content_tag :i do  %>
  <div class="fa fa-retweet"></div>
  Any text
<% end %>
```

Comment: content_tag :i, ('<i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>').html_safe this one worked for me since I would be putting it in the erb file. Thanks!